# How can I execute python.exe to open as if I opened it from the anaconda environment named "base"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

The file path: "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\python.exe"

When I open python from the path above, python shows the following warning:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Then when I try to import numpy or pandas, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

>>>
```

If I launch python from the anaconda terminal, python works perfectly fine.  I show this by importin numpy and pandas.  I import sys and print sys.executable to show that anaconda is using the same python executable python.exe.

```
(base) C:\Users\Disander>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\Disander\anaconda3\python.exe
>>>
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

I also tried to activate the (base) environment after executing python.exe.  Below, I show what happened when I tried using "os.system('conda activate base')"

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('conda activate base')
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
>>>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to execute the python.exe file as if I executed it from anaconda using the (base) environment.  I need this because I have another application depending on this executable.  The same application uses it to import modules such as numpy and pandas but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need first be sure that "Scripts" folder is in your path environment (C:\Anaconda3\Scripts, for my setup).
Then

```
activate environment_name
```

in CMD should work. Replace 'environment_name' with 'base' if you want 'base' activated.

Comment: Actually this is not "as if" executed from an anaconda environment, but his "is" activating the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Anaconda prompt or `conda activate`. Then print the path environment to the console via

`(base) C:\> path`

Add every listed folder below the Anaconda installation folder `..\Anaconda3\` to your user environment `PATH` variable. This will allow Python to also find numpy's C-Libraries.

```
\Anaconda3;
\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
\Anaconda3\Scripts;
\Anaconda3\bin;
```

Of cause this all ruins conda's well elaborated environment concept. So make sure you know what you're doing.

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDIT:**

If you have another application that depends on Python running in an Anacoda environment - like for example PowerBI Desktop - simply run that other application from the Anaconda prompt too.

**EDIT AFTER 2ND QUESTION EDIT**

If `conda` isn't recognized from `os` you clearly missed to initialize your shells via

`conda init --all`

Basically this is done during Anaconda installation by default, but some people prefer to skip this step for whatever reason.